# Is there any way to bypass the usage of loops in the following problem?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have two arrays of same length, viz.

```
(x_1, x_2,... , x_n)
```

and

```
(y_1, y_2,... , y_n).
```

Now for any i < j,

```
declare 1 if [(x_i = x_j and y_i = y_j) or (x_i ≠ x_j and y_i ≠ y_j)], 
else declare 0.
```

Suppose n is bigger than or equal to 100000. Now how can I store this array of 1's and 0's in an efficient way? The usage of a loop fails for both in R and Python.

P.S. I am from statistics background.

Comment: If `n` is 100000, then the output array will have 5 billion entries. So I think you need to give us more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: some tips I can provide: 1. Use a more efficient programming language (like C++ or Rust). 2. Write your data to the disk in chunks to avoid memory overflow. 3. Your task seems like one that is very easily parallelizable so if you have access to a cluster (many universities have something like that) it might be useful ...

Comment: Theoretically you could use recursion without loops, but that's not more efficient.

Comment: Can you give example input and output? Is the order of the 0/1 in the output important? *"How can I store...?"*: is your question about how to efficiently *store*, or how to efficiently *derive*?

Comment: The usage of for loop fails? Give us the code!